# Ayuda con este ejercicio c++ : impirimir terminos de la serie

Tags: c++, while

Escriba un programa que lea un numero entero n>0 y que imprima n terminos de la serie 4,12,24,40,60 ... Debe imprimir tambien la suma de n terminos

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: lo que no entiendo es como hacer la contanste porque la razon va aunmentando es 8 luego 12 y luego 16

Comment: Es simple, la constante es `n=4`, donde en cada iteración se le suma 4 `n=n+4` y eso se lo sumas a tu valor actual de la serie. Tus variables se verían así al ser inicializadas: `n=4; y=4` y en cada iteración haces esto: `n +=4; y +=n` por poner un ejemplo

Comment: [a(n) = 2*n*(n+1)](https://oeis.org/A046092)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es más matemático que de programación, lo primero es adivinar qué ley sigue la serie. No hay una manera única de lograr tal cosa.

Lo que yo haría es primero ver que todos son multiplos de cuatro, y tras dividir me queda 1,3,6,10,15 ; estos términos están separados por 2 3 4 5... Con esto ya podrías descubrir la ley y por lo tanto generar la secuencia.